# Analyzing the ANR I occurred in android 8.0

Tags: process, deadlock, android-8.0-oreo, android-binder

The ANR was from a Monkey test, the probability of this issue is about 10%. It seems that there was a deadlock happened in binder driver, but I can't get more information from this ANR log, anyone could give me some hints or suggestions on tackling this issue, the ANR main thread log is blow:

```
main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
 | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x73934670 self=0x713c0bea00
 | sysTid=970 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x71407e79b0
 | state=S schedstat=( 831520316 194654809 2975 ) utm=60 stm=22 core=7 HZ=100
 | stack=0x7ffc526000-0x7ffc528000 stackSize=8MB
 | held mutexes=
 kernel: __switch_to+0x9c/0xb0
 kernel: binder_thread_read+0x46c/0x1098
 kernel: binder_ioctl_write_read+0x218/0x344
 kernel: binder_ioctl+0x518/0x758
 kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x440/0x5e0
 kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x90/0xa4
 kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
 native: #00 pc 00000000000686bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
 native: #01 pc 0000000000023ed0  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+132)
 native: #02 pc 0000000000061a10  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+256)
 native: #03 pc 0000000000062690  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState15waitForResponseEPNS_6ParcelEPi+60)
 native: #04 pc 00000000000624c8  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState8transactEijRKNS_6ParcelEPS1_j+216)
 native: #05 pc 0000000000056d98  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android8BpBinder8transactEjRKNS_6ParcelEPS1_j+72)
 native: #06 pc 000000000011ebf4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
 native: #07 pc 0000000000928344  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+196)
 at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native method)
 at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:748)
 at com.android.ims.internal.IImsService$Stub$Proxy.turnOnIms(IImsService.java:523)
 at android.telephony.ims.ImsServiceProxyCompat.turnOnIms(ImsServiceProxyCompat.java:134)
 at com.android.ims.ImsManager.turnOnIms(ImsManager.java:2104)
 at com.android.ims.ImsManager.updateImsServiceConfig(ImsManager.java:1242)
 at com.android.internal.telephony.imsphone.ImsPhoneCallTracker.onDataEnabledChanged(ImsPhoneCallTracker.java:3195)
 at com.android.internal.telephony.imsphone.ImsPhoneCallTracker.handleMessage(ImsPhoneCallTracker.java:2706)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Did you work this out? I'm having an ANR  that is getting stuck in kernel like this, and have no clue how to debug this!

Comment: That happened years ago. I remembered that there maybe are time-consuming events that happened in  ImsManager.turnOnIms related codes. You should pay attention to the application code.